# Go channels -- what is happening here

Tags: go

I am learning go channels from Go Tour example on web crawler exercise.

My understanding is

```golang
go func ()
```

runs the func in the background, if nothing blocks it should just finish the func and return.

But it seems like go Crawl( ) below does nothing. Am I understanding this right?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("u is ", u)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean “does nothing”? Does the goroutine not run (maybe show the output)? Or are you asking why `go` is used there?

Comment: I expect this line  "fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)" to print the content of u passed to the go Crawl, but nothing gets printed.

Comment: Show the code that initializes the value `fetcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Go program terminates when the `main` method of the `main` package returns. Upon so doing, the program (including all goroutines) immediately exits. See the [Go language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

In this instance, your `Crawl` method spawns several goroutines and immediately returns, without synchronising on those goroutines to wait for them to complete. Upon so doing, control flow returns to `main`, which reaches the end of the function and implicitly returns, halting your program. Note that this interleaving behaviour is not deterministic – in some cases, you *could* get output from some goroutines, but it is very unlikely they will be scheduled for execution so promptly.

You need to implement a mechanism for `Crawl` to block awaiting the results of the goroutines it spawns. There are several mechanisms for doing this, the most common and recommended being use of a [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Comment: Ah, I see. This was so puzzling, thank you for help.